# How to redirect port 6006 to port 80 in a web app?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-webapps

I created a web app from a DockerHub container where TensorBoard is running on port 6006. The website cannot be displayed and it seems that Azure websites only expose port 80.

The `Networking` tab, where I usually expose and redirect ports for virtual machines, shows only "Azure CDN" and "IP Restrictions".

How can I view the web app running on port 6006?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure web apps, ports are under "Application Settings", not under "Networking". Redirect port 6006 to port 80 by clicking on your app, then on Application Settings in the left blade. Under the "Application Settings" heading, click "Add new setting" with value `80:6006`.